# How to make a button file-input and send to server at same time in php?

Tags: javascript, html

in my code I have 2 button. first of them is file-input and another send to server that file. How can I do that with only 1 button in my site?
her is my php code:

```js
const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("real-file");
const customBtn = document.getElementById("custom-button");
customBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  realFileBtn.click();
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="real-file" hidden="hidden">
  <input type="submit" value="Göndər" id="custom-button">
</form>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<?php
    $files = scandir("uploader");    
    ?>
```

Comment: There's only one button. `real-file` is a file input, not a button.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for that but, how can i make my button pick and send to server same time.

Comment: I think your code already does that. When I click on the button a file chooser displays, and when I select a file it submits the form.

Comment: @Barmar no it isn't, i checked it. it works when i do it manually to choose a file and send to server with button but not with one button

Comment: Try the snippet in the question. It will try to submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go.

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input')
const button = document.getElementById('custom-button')
fileInput.onchange = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    document.getElementById('my-form').submit()
};
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fileInput.click()
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" id="my-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file-input" hidden="hidden">
    <button value="Göndər" id="custom-button">Gönder</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call form submit when there is file changed by

```
document.getElementById("real-file").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
};
```

Comment: There's no `id="form"`

Comment: add the `id="form"` to the form element